# HttpResponse to string length 0 is returned

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an HTTPGet request on a server in an Android APP, but when I change the httpresponse in string, the string is 0 length.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://"+server+path+"?assets="+URLEncoder.encode(query, "US-ASCII")+"&lt="+localTime+"&to="+timeOffset);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
System.out.println("Status"+ response.getStatusLine());
System.out.println("Length "+org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).length());
return org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Catlog :

```
I/System.out(22344): StatusHTTP/1.1 200 OK
I/System.out(21737): Length 0
```

The uri is good,when I copy/past it in a browser I have a result like this :

```
{"ads":[{"i"...],"pxs":{}}
```

Does anyone have an idea why my string is empty?

Udpate 1:

```
    long localTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date date = new Date();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int timeOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset ();
```

Update 2:

I added this line :

```
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)");
```

And now I have this error :

Catlog

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
 E/AndroidRuntime(23584):   at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
```

Comment: What are `localTime` and `timeOffset`? Construct the URL in a separate step, print its value, paste that in a browser, and verify that you get content back.

Comment: Lately, I've noticed that some resources require a meaningful user agent to prevent dumb bots from scraping data etc. - it might be worth trying to spoof an IE user agent, e.g. `httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)");`

Comment: @Perception I copy and past the url after constructing it and I get content back.

Comment: So what does your code return on another URL? Such as `"http://www.stackoverflow.com"`.

Comment: @jglouie I add your line, now the length of the string is not null but I have an error, I update my post.

Comment: @infgeoax I am not sure to understand what is your question. Yes the parameter in HttpGet(..) is a well formed URL, when I copy/past the result on browser I have a content back. This content is a json.

Comment: I was suggesting that you try another server, preferably one that is publicly available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Length "+org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).length());
return org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

You are using it twice. Thats why you get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
```

try setting it to a reference.

```
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

then do what you have to do with responseText.